# run python program one by one

Tags: python

Is possible to run bunch of python based program one by one in python terminal? I have number of program that is executed in Python. I want to make a single file, so that I can just run a single python file, and it will execute each program one by one in that file.
Single file:some_files.py

```
\home\something\1.py
\home\something\2.py
\home\something\3.py
\home\something\4.py
```

Comment: you can use subprocess

Comment: Subprocess if overkill I think. You can create a file that import all the files, then run the main function.

Comment: @justhalf If you don't know what the processes do with whatever process-relevant settings, it might be preferrable to run each program as a different process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use more simple approch in Subprocess module,

```
import os
os.chdir('\home\something\')
import subprocess`
subprocess.call(['python','1.py'])
subprocess.call(['python','2.py'])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two very easy ways to achieve the same goal, *without* using a python script nor python terminal (I'm aware that's not exacly what you're asking, but it's very easy).

#### An IPython script

run_all.ipy (.ipy is the extension for ipython scripts)

```
%run \home\something\1.py
%run \home\something\2.py
%run \home\something\3.py
%run \home\something\4.py
```

#### A shell/batch script

(on windows use a batch file (.bat) instead)

run_all.sh

```
python \home\something\1.py
python \home\something\2.py
python \home\something\3.py
python \home\something\4.py
```

Comment: I was trying to run in a Shell. But everytime I got only one error,
[Errno 2] No such file or directory/../..

Comment: If you post your script and command line you're running, it would be easier to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the suprocess build-in library.

```
   import subprocess

   prog_max = 10
   for i in range(prog_max):
      s = subprocess.Popen(['python','%i.py'%i], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
      out,_ = s.communicate()
```